# Gradle error after studio update

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, yahoo-squidb

I've recently upgraded from `1.2.2` to `1.3.2` and was introduced with the following error:

`Error:Unable to load class 'org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.DefaultMavenFactory'.`

> Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - You are using JDK version 'java version "1.7.0_79"'. Some versions of JDK 1.7 (e.g. 1.7.0_10) may cause class loading errors in Gradle.
>     Please update to a newer version (e.g. 1.7.0_67).
>
> Open JDK Settings
>
> Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>
> Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
>
> The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
>   Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
>
> Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

My project is using the *SquiDB* library if that matters, has anyone encountered similar error and could help me out how to fix it?

Answer (score 13):

I don't know why but following has worked:

Open the `Settings panel`

Go to `Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle`

On right in the form under the `Project-level settings` heading select `Use default gradle wrapper (Recommended)`

In my case I had selected `Use local gradle distribution` for some reason.

if you know the reason behind the issue and solution applied please add another answer with explanation and I will make it accepted.

Comment: Wow, could never have guessed this one. One Setting can ruin an entire day. Kudos Google! :/

Answer (score 13):

if your `gradle.properties` file which is located at the root level of your project contains :

`classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'`,

try to change to:

`classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'`

I solved the same problem in this way, and hope you will as well.